# One Backbone model for several views, who handles the fetch()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, synchronization

Having a Backbone model shared between several views is a rather common situation. Nevertheless, let's say this model is a `UserModel`. It handles several methods, allowing a user to register or login for instance.

And when the user is logged, fetch is called to get the user's data. Therefor the model can't fetch itself with `this.fetch()` in its `initialize` method.

Where shoud it be fetched from? How?

This is our simple `UserModel`:

```
const UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // get url for 'me' (ie connected user)
    url() {
        return app.endpoint + '/users/me/' + app.conToken;
    },

    login(email, password, rememberMe, callback) {
        …
    },

    signup(email, password, firstname, lastname, callback) {
        …
    }
});
```

Now let's say it's shared by both:

`HomeView` & `CartView`

```
app.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: app.tpl.home,

    initialize() {
        // model is passed @ instanciation
        this.model.fetch();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    },

    render() {
       …
    }
});


app.CartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: app.tpl.cart,

    initialize() {
        // model is passed @ instanciation
        this.model.fetch();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    },

    render() {
       …
    }
});
```

Now if I instanciate `HomeView`, `userModel` will be fetched. But if at a later point, I instanciate `CartView`, this same model will be fetched again. And that makes a useless http request.

Basically, the model could fetch istself after a succesfull call to its `login` method, but user can arrive on a page or reload his browser being already logged in. Furthermore, a user can land on any page, there's no way to say he's going to `HomeView` prior to `CartView`.

There are two options I see. Either `UserModel` smartly handles multiple `fetch` calls like so:

```
const UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // get url for 'me' (ie connected user)
    url() {
        return app.endpoint + '/users/me/' + app.conToken;
    },

    isSync() {
        // an hour ago
        let hourAgo = Date.now() - 3600000;

        // data has been fetched less than an hour ago
        if (this.fetchTime && hourAgo > this.fetchTime) return true;
        return false;
    },

    fetch() {
        // has not already fetched data or data is older than an hour
        if (!this.isSync()) {
            this.fetchTime = Date.now();
            this.fetch();

            return;
        }

        // trigger sync without issuing any http call
        this.trigger('sync');
    },

    …
});
```

That way, I'm able to call `this.model.fetch()` as many times as needed, being stateless in views.

Or, I can handle that on a view layer:

```
app.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: app.tpl.home,

    initialize() {
        // model is passed @ instanciation

        // fetch model if empty
        if (_.isEmpty(this.model.changed)) this.fetch();

        // render directly if already populated
        else this.render();

        // render on model sync
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    },

    render() {
       …
    }
});
```

If needed, [Backbone's `model.changed`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed) doc reference & Underscore's [`_.isEmpty`'s](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty).

Which way is cleaner? Is there any other approach I might have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personal preference would not be to override `fetch` but to instead implement a wrapper function, like `customFetch`

```
const UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
// get url for 'me' (ie connected user)
url() {
    return app.endpoint + '/users/me/' + app.conToken;
},

isSync() {
    // an hour ago
    let hourAgo = Date.now() - 3600000;

    // data has been fetched less than an hour ago
    if (this.fetchTime && hourAgo > this.fetchTime) return true;
    return false;
},

customFetch() {
    // has not already fetched data or data is older than an hour
    if (!this.isSync()) {
        this.fetchTime = Date.now();
        this.fetch();

        return;
    }

    // trigger sync without issuing any http call
    this.trigger('sync');
},

…
});
```

The code example you provided would end up in a loop (`this.fetch` calling itself...), so my personal preference is to just wrap the core backbone functionality in another function.

I would even go so far as to have my own custom `Model` that is extended by all the models I use. Eg:

```
const MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    isSync() {
        // an hour ago
       let hourAgo = Date.now() - 3600000;

       // data has been fetched less than an hour ago
       return (this.fetchTime && hourAgo > this.fetchTime);
    },
    customFetch() {
        this.fetch();
    }, 
});
```

Then `UserModel` would override `customFetch` and look like this:

```
const UserModel = MyModel.extend({
    customFetch() {
        // has not already fetched data or data is older than an hour
        if (!this.isSync()) {
            this.fetchTime = Date.now();
            this.fetch();
            return;
        }

        // trigger sync without issuing any http call
       this.trigger('sync');
    },
});
```

Might not be the best way to do it. For me personally it would be the easy way for it to read and then extend later. I would imagine this `customFetch` would be used in some/all models so it could be amended as appropriate.

Comment: +1 for the endless loop, it's obvious I hadn't tested it :p Having a custom base model sounds great! Why having `UserModel` override `customFetch` though? It could be directly declared as is in the base class. Then I would call `customFetch` in views where I just wanna make sure model is populated or directly `fetch` when I need to deal with the most up to date data.

Comment: @Buzut well again its my personal preference again. Lets set we had a `TimeModel` that also extends `MyModel`, this model we would want to `fetch` every time. I would prefer to write `customFetch` everywhere in my code rather than mix `customFetch` and `fetch`. You could quite easily set `customFetch` in `MyModel` to be your custom code. So again, just this is just how it makes sense to me, hopefully my reasoning makes sense. Ultimately it whatever reads best for you, but try to be consistent with your approach.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear, and for taking the time to propose a thorough answer.

Comment: Thats ok. Backbone is a very powerful beast, purely because it doesn't require you to do anything in a given way. So you'll find that creating a `MyModel` and even a `MyView` will cut down on a lot of repetitive code. I would also highly recommend looking into [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) to help with `views`

Comment: I love Backbone because of its minimalist approach and the great level of control it gives the developer (no magic things à la Angular). Nevertheless, sometimes I want to make sure "my way" is elegant. I've read a lot of [Derick Balay's posts on Backbone](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone/) (Marionnette creator). I use some things like regionManager from Marionnette, but where I can, I like to keep Backbone "raw"!